# Searching for newlines in a Oracle DB using SQL 'like' clause

Tags: sql, oracle, select, newline, like-keyword

I'm trying to see if a particular column in a table in my Oracle database has any strings which contain a newline character, so a wildcard, a newline, and another wildcard.

I've tried the like command and a combination with CHR(10) and tried escaping the newline itself, but to no avail. What would be the proper way to detect a newline in somewhere within a string?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`like '%'||chr(10)||'%'` ought to work.

Answer (score 4):

`select * from yourTable where InStr(yourCol, Chr(10))>0` would work

Comment: +1 for extreme cases I'd expect this solution to perform a little better than using LIKE